# GraphQL how to wrap a query

Tags: graphql

For example, I have the following queries: `testA` and `testB`.

I would like to get the following response:

```
{
  data: {
    test: {
      a: {
        id: 1
      },
      b: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Now my query looks like:

```
query {
  testA {
    id
  }

  testB {
    id
  }
}
```

I know that I can use aliases like this:

```
query {
  a: testA {
    id
  }

  b: testB {
    id
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to *wrap it into a block*.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can make multiple queries, but you can't combine their responses into a single response.

Comment: Oh, that's bad :(

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it - all responses are typed, so you know what shape to expect. In your case, you're trying to change that shape, so you'd have to either add a new type to the schema or do the transformation yourself when you get the data back.

Comment: @goto1, yes, but I do not have the access to the schema. I was thinking about this like syntactic sugar, but seems like this is not possible for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GraphQL service includes a schema that consists of one or more types that describe the possible shape or structure of the response. The schema could be modified to allow you to get the desired response, but it's not possible to apply arbitrary transformations to what is the expected response.